# Empty Set literal syntax

Tags: crystal-lang

Looking for the right syntax or if there's a bug/rough edge:

```
Set{}

for empty hashes use '{} of KeyType => ValueType' <-wrong

Set{} of Char

expecting token '=>', not 'EOF' <-wrong

Set(Char){}

for empty hashes use '{} of KeyType => ValueType' <-wrong

Set(Char).new # not a literal

Set{'a'} # not an empty Set literal
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't one, use `Set(Char).new`.

Set literals, such as `Set{'a'}` actually compile to:

```
__tmp_var = Set(typeof('a')).new
__tmp_var << 'a'
__tmp_var
```

so there's no performance benefit to using an empty literal instead of `Set(Char).new`

Comment: Thanks, it was was to avoid code ugliness. Not one at present, I'm sure a little precedence magic can make it nicer.